# How to disable predictive text suggestions when typing on the website?

Tags: support

Sometimes when I type, Stack Overflow will attempt to predict what I will type next and provide a suggestion as a shortcut. I can click tab to quickly use the prediction.

[image: red arrow pointing to a suggested text prediction]

How can I completely disable this feature so that I don't see any predictions?

Comment: Are you sure this is being provided by SO?

Comment: I didn't think about that so I'm not sure at all. I am using Microsoft Edge but I don't have any plug-ins that do this.

Comment: Ahh. It was the Edge browser doing this. I navigated to `edge://settings/languages` and unchecked 'Use text prediction`.

Comment: Guess i know what to look out for when i install this update

Comment: Is this an off-topic question?

Comment: @AugustoVasques I'm not sure, but I naturally thought this feature was part of SO. Does it make sense to keep this question as it is so that users who think like me can find it more easily?

Comment: Might be best to add self answer then, for the sake of others.

Comment: I flagged it as off-topic because if we keep such a specific post for Edge users, we should also be fair and keep a similar post to serve users of other browsers and platforms.

Comment: Most browsers don't sneak in text prediction on the desktop tho

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to Stack Exchange at all. With that browser-specific setting enabled, it would happen in any form field on any web site, no?

Answer (score 7):

The text predictions were not being provided by Stack Overflow, but by the Microsoft Edge browser.

To disable it, navigate to `edge://settings/languages` and untoggle *Use text prediction*.